# Kotlin : How not to repeat math operations if there is no number in front of it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

Hello I have made a simple calculator in "Kotlin" using android studio
the problem I got and I don't have a way to fix it is how not to repeat the math operations after typing a number .. Perhaps because I am new to the world of Android application development and I do not know the way I should avoid this problem.

Example for what I mean, He entered addition/subtraction twice:

[image]

My codes :
**Main.kt**

```
  package com.iosmostafa.calculator
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.util.Log
    import com.iosmostafa.calculator.R
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    import net.objecthunter.exp4j.ExpressionBuilder
    
    class Main : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            //Numbers
            tvOne.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("1", true) }
            tvTwo.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("2", true) }
            tvThree.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("3", true) }
            tvFour.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("4", true) }
            tvFive.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("5", true) }
            tvSix.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("6", true) }
            tvSeven.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("7", true) }
            tvEight.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("8", true) }
            tvNine.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("9", true) }
            tvZero.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("0", true) }
            tvDot.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion(".", true) }
    
    
    
            //Operators
            tvPlus.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("+", false) }
            tvMinus.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("-", false) }
            tvMul.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("*", false) }
            tvDivide.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("/", false) }
            tvOpen.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("(", false) }
            tvClose.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion(")", false) }
            tvNew1.setOnClickListener{(appendOnExpresstion("%",false))}
    
            tvClear.setOnClickListener {
                tvExpression.text = ""
                tvResult.text = ""
            }
    
            tvBack.setOnClickListener {
                val string = tvExpression.text.toString()
                if(string.isNotEmpty()){
                    tvExpression.text = string.substring(0,string.length-1)
                }
                tvResult.text = ""
            }
    
    
    
            tvEquals.setOnClickListener {
                try {
    
                    val expression = ExpressionBuilder(tvExpression.text.toString()).build()
                    val result = expression.evaluate()
                    val longResult = result.toLong()
                    if(result == longResult.toDouble())
                        tvResult.text = longResult.toString()
                    else
                        tvResult.text = result.toString()
    
                }catch (e:Exception){
                    Log.d("Exception"," message : " + e.message )
                }
            }
    
    
        }
    
        fun appendOnExpresstion(string: String, canClear: Boolean) {
    
            if(tvResult.text.isNotEmpty()){
                tvExpression.text = ""
            }
    
            if (canClear) {
                tvResult.text = ""
                tvExpression.append(string)
            } else {
                tvExpression.append(tvResult.text)
                tvExpression.append(string)
                tvResult.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvExpression"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80sp"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/numberButton"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/numberButton"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvClear"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="حذف" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOpen"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="(" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvClose"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text=")" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNew1"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDivide"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="/" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSeven"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEight"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="8" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNine"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="9" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMul"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="X" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFour"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFive"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSix"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="6" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMinus"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="-" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOne"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTwo"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvThree"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPlus"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="+" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDot"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvZero"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tvBack"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/backspace" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEquals"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="=" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers didn't work, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since you apparently got your answer there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace your "+" operator to prohibit this pattern?

```java
tvPlus.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstionNoDups("+", false) }
```

```java
fun appendOnExpresstionNoDups(string: String, canClear: Boolean) {
    val lastIndex = tvExpression.text.toString().length()-1
    val string = tvExpression.text.toString().toCharArray()[lastIndex]
    if(string != "+") {
       appendOnExpresstion(string, canClear)
    }
}
```

I omitted edge case conditionals for simplicity. I've also never used kotlin before, so you may need to fidget with the syntax a little.

Comment: hey paul thanx for your attention , where should i add your code in my app?

Comment: replace your "+" expression with the appendOnExpresstionNoDups that I've written for you

Comment: i replace it when i click in "+" its add a the same number I insert

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Kotlin thing, you need to write some logic in your app that handles an operator button press, and decides whether it should be added or not, or if the last operator should be changed to the new one, that kind of thing. You need to be able to explain how it should work, before you start writing code that follows that behaviour.

@PaulNikonowicz 's suggestion is one way of doing it that fits with your current code - it's basically saying "if the user presses the + button, check if the display ends in a +, and *only call the `appendOnExpression` method if it doesn't*. You're running a check to see if it's valid before performing the operation, and stopping it from moving to an invalid state.

Calculators can be surprisingly tricky! There's a bunch of logic involved in making them act consistently, like a state machine. Having a separate method for operators that runs some validation is a good start (although you could just make it replace the last character if that's an operator, usually with a calculator if you press + and then change your mind and press -, it will use the last one you pressed)